# What constitutes an invention?

Tags: us20140302201

In reference to the patent: [US20140302201](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140302201)

The use of gum arabic in wine has been allowed for a long time (see the Codex Oeunolgic Statu)

How is this invention an 'invention'?

Comment: Gilles - I have tried to correct your spelling and grammar, and removed your ALL CAPS, but I can't find a link to the Codex you mention.

Answer (score 1):

US 20140302201 is a published patent application waiting for examination.

During examination the examiner will consider whether or not the applicant's claimed invention, as defined by the claims, defines a patentable invention. If the combination of elements required by applicant's claims was taught by the prior art (e.g., the Codex Oeunoligic), I would expect the examiner to reject the claimed invention.

To issue as a patent, the applicant would then need to a amend the claims to be non-obvious over the prior art. How an examiner determines whether or not the claimed invention is obvious is discussed in [MPEP 2143](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2143.html). Also see [MPEP 2144.05](http://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s2144.html#d0e211255) which discusses the obviousness of ranges.